# Pyqt: Auto-arrange multiple windows on launch (Simulate windows key + arrows)

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt5

My MainWindow starts a process where 1, 2, 3 or more logging MainWindows pop up. Currently, they all launch on top of each other and block the GUI, requiring you to drag them away from each other. I'd like my app to position the windows automatically in a grid to the left with the main app to the right. Similar to how you can position windows with the Windows key + Left/Right/Up arrow. Or, to have it similar to how launching multiple command prompts at the same time neatly stack slightly overlapping each other diagonally.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Get the geometry of the [`primaryScreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop) and compute the geometry of all the windows on startup. Qt doesn't provide this on its own.